# Executing a makefile command from meson?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, meson-build

I wanted to try to execute 'make install' command from a makefile automatically with meson.
I tried the following in a meson.build file:

```
r = run_command('make install')

    if r.returncode() != 0
      # it failed
    endif
    output = r.stdout().strip()
    errortxt = r.stderr().strip()
```

But it prints the following error: `Program or command 'make install' not found or not executable.`
This meson.build file is located in the same directory as my makefile. Is this not the way to use this functionality or is there a better way to acheive what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument is the command (binary) followed by its arguments:

```
run_command('make', 'install')
```

Comment: Ah yes. It said so in the documentation but I didn't read it carefully. Now when I run it with this change there are no errors but the makefile doesn't seem to be executed. Could it be that the directory in which the command is running doesn't contain the makefile? If so, is there a way I can set that directory?

Comment: Did you see this part "The command is run from an unspecified directory, and Meson will set three environment variables MESON_SOURCE_ROOT, MESON_BUILD_ROOT and MESON_SUBDIR that specify the source directory, build directory and subdirectory the target was defined in, respectively."?

Comment: They write a wrapper script here: https://sourceforge.net/p/meson/wiki/Run%20targets/ but make also accepts a -C to change the directory first.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, in order set the directory for running the command `run_command('make', 'install')` I need to create a script shown in the example? Why can't I just do something like this: `run_command('cd', meson.source_root())'? I apologize if this is not a coherent question since I am very new to meson and project building in general.

Comment: Also, when replicating the example script shown in sourceforge.net/p/meson/wiki/Run%20targets it shows the following error: Run_target takes only one positional argument: the target name.

Comment: Try.  What did you find?  The first argument is a command and cd is a internal command of your shell. You can do: '/usr/bin/bash', '-c "cd $MESON_SOURCE_ROOT; make install"') or as I said use the -C feature of make to do 'make', '-C path').  I don't know if if meson supports interpolating values into strings for -C option, or if you can set a variable like that.

Comment: I tried something like this `makefile_dir = meson.source_root()
make_command = '-C @0@ install'
make_command = make_command.format(makefile_dir)

r = run_command('make', make_command)` make_command: contains '-C themakefilepath install' where the makefile path is correct as I have output and checked it. So the entire command should work fine but it just doesn't work. When I rebuild my program I expect this command to have been executed but it never has.

Comment: `if r.returncode() != 0
  message('makefile execution failed')
endif
output = r.stdout().strip()
errortxt = r.stderr().strip()` This outputs the error message which means run_command failed. But why did it fail? I am just so confused.

Comment: Does your make field depend on any environment variables?   Was the output?  If you run make with shell you capture the output into a file with make install >& /tmp/make.log.  I rarely find make -d debug output useful.

Comment: Make field only depends on $HOME variable. It looks something like this `make install:
 mkdir  -p $HOME/.dirname` and more commands like that which only depend on $HOME.  Output is this `mkdir  -p OME/.dirname
...` I am not sure why it outputs OME instead of HOME but there aren't any error messages.

Comment: Probably also PATH